# Outlook New Email notification - Not working

Tags: email, windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a pile of rules set with incoming messages going to various folders filed under my Inbox. My issue is I have to keep checking these folders to see if there is new messages as my new mail notification only seems to work for something that comes in to the Inbox.

Any thoughts/solutions?
Windows X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your rule 'display a Desktop Alert' in the 'Select Action(s)' setting.  That should pop a notification when you receive an email in which the rule applies to.